# Android Media player play the song x times

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I would like to play the song x times like 1,2,3 ..etc using android media player.Please 
let me know is there any way to do this using android api.
Thanks

Comment: Why don' t you simply override onCompletion method and start your media again, if your counter doesn' t reach your specific value?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried, only than user can help you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As Wamasa said, you could use setLooping for infinite playing.
For playing only a specific count time, you can add an onCompletionListener to your MediaPlayer:

```
int count = 0; // initialise outside listener to prevent looping

mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
  int maxCount = 3;

  @Override
  public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
    if(count < maxCount) {
      count++;
      mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
      mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}});
```

Comment: i will try with this code and let you know.I think it would be mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition).currentposition represents which song r u playing right now.

Comment: Does it place a gap between loops?

Comment: @RAWNAKYAZDANI No, it doesn't, but you could add it before starting over.

Comment: Does not work for me. Nothing is played.  Further, the variable decleratrion `int count = 0` yields an error regarding inner class.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a MediaPlayer class try using MediaPlayer.setLooping(true)

Comment: Im using mediaplayer class but setLooping is to repeat forever.But i want to tell the mediaplayer play song1 2 times and song2 3 times and song4 1 time.Please let me know your comments.

Comment: By the way, Android's SoundPool has a way to set a finite number of looping. Take a look at <a http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/SoundPool.html