# MusicPlayer music repeat "X" times

Tags: java, android, audio-player, android-music-player

How can I make this simple music player musics repeat for example 5 times or to loop the music for 1, 2, or 3 hour.

This is my code of a simple music player with a music list:

```
public class Musica extends AppCompatActivity implements Runnable {
    private Button pause;
    private Button stop;
    private SeekBar mseek;
    private MediaPlayer mp;
    private Thread soundThread;
    private Button play;

    //list
    AdRequest adRequest;
    private AdView adView;

    ListView listm;

    String[] itemname = {
            "music 1",
            "music 2",
            "music 3",
            "music 4",
            "music 5",
            "music 6",
            "Lullaby 1",
            "Lullaby 2",
            "Lullaby 3",
            "Lullaby 4",
            "Lullaby 5",

    };


    Integer[] imgid = {
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,
            R.drawable.musicon,

    };


    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_musica);

        getSupportActionBar().hide();



        adView = (AdView)findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .build();
        adView.loadAd(adRequest);

        adView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {

            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                adView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int error) {
                adView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        });


        CustomListAdapterMusic adapter = new CustomListAdapterMusic(this, itemname, imgid);
        listm = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listmusic);
        listm.setAdapter(adapter);

        listm.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String Slecteditem = itemname[+position];
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), Slecteditem, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                if (position == 0) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.babyone);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 1) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.babytwo);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 2) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.water);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 3) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.ocean);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 4) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.rain);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 5) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.sm);
                    mp.start();
                }
                if (position == 6) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.classica);
                    mp.start();
                }


                if (position == 7) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.relax6);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if (position == 8) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.twinkle7);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if (position == 9) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.ninar11);
                    mp.start();
                }

                if (position == 10) {

                    stopPlaying();

                    mp = MediaPlayer.create(Musica.this.getBaseContext(), R.raw.lullaby9);
                    mp.start();
                }



                play = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bplay);
                pause = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bpause);
                stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bstop);
                mseek = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar);


                setupListeners();
                soundThread = new Thread(Musica.this);
                soundThread.start();


            }


        });


    }

    private void stopPlaying() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.stop();
            mp.release();
            mp = null;
        }
    }


    private void setupListeners()

    {


        play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();

            }
        });


        pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.pause();

            }
        });


        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View currentView) {
                mp.stop();

            }
        });


        mseek.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                if (fromUser) {
                    mp.seekTo(progress);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });


    }


    @Override
    public void run() {
        int currentPosition = 0;
        int soundTotal = mp.getDuration();
        mseek.setMax(soundTotal);


        while (mp != null && currentPosition < soundTotal) {

            try {
                Thread.sleep(300);
                currentPosition = mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException SoundException) {
                return;

            } catch (Exception otherException) {
                return;

            }
            mseek.setProgress(currentPosition);


        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For part one, implement an `setOnCompletionListener` as already answered here: [Android Media player play the song x times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457644/android-media-player-play-the-song-x-times)

For repeating for for 1 hour, change the counter with the timer implementation:

```
// get current time in milliseconds + 1 hour
long tRef = System.currentTimeMillis() + 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000L;
// set listener
mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener(){
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
        // current time
        long tNow = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (tNow < tEnd) {
            mediaPlayer.seekTo(0);
            mediaPlayer.start();
        }
}});
```

To trigger the looping again, you just need to set the `tRef` to a new value.

Side note: If you need both functionalities at the same time, then combine them into one listener as you cannot have two listeners on the same media player at the same time.

Alternative solution would be to set `mp.setLooping()` and make a timer task to turn it off, but I would not recommend it here, as it might require some lifecycle management.

```
Timer timerObj = new Timer();
TimerTask timerTaskObj = new TimerTask() {
    public void run() {
        if (mp != null) {
            mp.setLooping(false)
        }
    }
};
timer.schedule(timerTaskObj, 0, 1 * 60 * 60 * 1000L);
```