# How to do audio loop 15 times in android java

Tags: java, android

How do I loop the audio 15 times in Android Java? If only ** mediaPlayer.setLooping (true); ** then the loop will not stop. I want to repeat 1 minute audio for 15 times. So, later it will be repeated only 15 times and then it stops. How do friends?

```
public class BackgroundSoundService extends Service {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    String song = (String) extras.get("song");
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, this.getResources().getIdentifier(song,"raw", this.getPackageName()));
    **mediaPlayer.setLooping(true);**
    mediaPlayer.setVolume(75, 75);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Memulai Suara Alam....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return startId;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
}
```

}

Comment: Maybe this helps?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14457644/android-media-player-play-the-song-x-times

Comment: Can you help me to implement it? I really don't understand and want to understand it. I've tried it, but it's still error.

Comment: The oncompletion listener is called when the audio finishes playing once. When this listener is called, add 1 to the count variable, and play the audio again. If the count variable reaches maxCount, don't play again. This will let you loop the audio the amount of times you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using a for loop

```
    int loops = 16;

    for (int i = 0; i < loops; i++)
        {
             play song 
        }
```